# Exception in opening a file that is already open

Tags: c#

I am building an application in C# in which I have to open a CSV file to read data from it. I get an exception when I try to open the CSV file from C# when that file is already open in Excel. The exception says that the process cannot access the file since it is already open. How can I solve this problem and open the file even if it is opened in other application?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: please post some code to show us what you have done so far

Comment: This is the code: using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(csvOpenFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))

Comment: You're missing an argument. Read my answer.

Comment: Check the answer Hans provides below. FileShare.Read doesn't appear to work if the file is already open. FileShare.ReadWrite does work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I faced this problem some time back.

You are missing the `FileShare` parameter. Without specifying that, if you open a file, it will be locked exclusively by your application. But since it's already been opened by Excel (or any other app), you will receive an exception.

You can try using this - I think this will be your best bet -

`using (FileStream fs = File.Open(<file-path>, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))`

This code says: Hello Excel! If you may permit (read, not throw exception), I would like to read the file, though I will not try to own it and I know that you may modify it anytime.

If this throws error, then Excel has denied you even the read access. Too bad then!
All the best.

Comment: I found FileShare.Read did not work, while FileShare.ReadWrite did

Comment: Use FileShare.ReadWrite instead of FileShare.Read, as mentioned by Hans.

Comment: i had this problem and the `FileShare.ReadWrite` Fixed my problem after a while,only to notice that i had another using block where i called the method i got the exception on... so check your code, if you have this issue... something is definetly using the file...

Comment: Thanks! FileShare.ReadWrite fixed my problem!

Answer (score 8):

It is possible but you have to carefully control the file sharing you specify.  Most .NET classes default to FileShare.Read, denying another process from writing to the file.  But that cannot work if the file is opened by Excel, it already gained write access to it.  You cannot deny a right that was already acquired.

To fix the problem, make your code look similar to this:

```
        using (var fs = new FileStream(@"c:\\temp\\test.csv", FileMode.Open, 
                   FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs)) {
            // Read it...
        }
```

Note the use of FileShare.ReadWrite.  I verified this code works while Excel had test.csv opened.

Beware of the potential trouble you'll invite with this, odd things can happen when Excel writes to the file just as you are reading it.  You'll likely read garbage, part of old data, part of new, without a good way to diagnose this.

Answer (score 0):

Due to concurrency issues you can not have the option to write to two instances of the same file.  It should be possible to open one as read-only this would allow for there to not be a concurrency issue as reading is guaranteed to be thread safe.  [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc823095.aspx) should explain how to do what I proposed

Comment: I am opening the file from C# in Read-Only mode. But still I am getting this exception. What could be the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible.

A file can be opened with different kind of protection. Excel opens the file exclusively, for the purpose of protecting the file from being changed by some other program and then reverted back when Excel saves it.

Excel could have opened the file and allowed reading, but then you could end up in a deadlock situation where two applications have the file open for reading, and neither can save anything back to it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case based on the link I provided.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: That article is about opening a spreadsheet, not a CSV file, and about opening a file for read-only access, not opening a file that is already opened exclusively, so I'm sorry but it's not relevant at all.

Comment: actually it is quite relevant.  If OP takes a look at the order in which the files are opened you can have Excel open the file first as a Read-Only instance which would potentially mitigate the issue

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Yes, that would be possible, but the article is about the API, not the Excel application.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: No, it doesn't. Have you linked to the right article?

Comment: From the article: Create an instance of the SpreadsheetDocument class from the document  (This is the header)

In the Open XML SDK, the SpreadsheetDocument class represents an Excel document package.

Comment: here is the code: using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false))

Comment: @Woot4Moo: You are missing the point completely. I am talking about the *Excel Application*. If the OP was really opening the same file twice in different ways from his own program, don't you think that he would have asked about that instead?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992405/259), is to copy the file to a temporary file and open that.

Use

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourcepath, copypath, false);
```