# How to read open excel file at C#

Tags: c#, excel, file-io, ioexception

I want to read already open excel file with C#. I am using this method but it can't read the excel file while the file is open in Microsoft excel.

```
FileStream stream = File.Open("myfile.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

It gives `IOException: The process cannot access the file 'myfile.xlsx' because it is being used by another process.`

I hope you understands what I mean. I want to keep excel file open and while file is open at Microsoft excel i want to read it from C#. I am using C# net framework 4.0

Comment: You can't if the file is opened by on other process

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't any way to achive that ?

Comment: How about: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316126

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/898017/48082

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can still copy the file while excel has it open, so you could make a copy of the file and then open that.  Just make sure you clean up after yourself when you are done with the copy.

Answer (score 25):

You need to open it with FileShare.ReadWrite:

```
FileStream stream = File.Open("myfile.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/898017/46635).

Comment: This is not working for me still getting the same error message.

Comment: This works great for local files. However, it does not work for Excel files on OneDrive, even when Auto Save is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Interop library to use the already opened instance of Excel.

```
oExcel == (Excel.Application) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
```

Comment: what namespace do i need for this ?

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop   For more information just google for "Excel automation". Lots of info on the net ;-)

Comment: Noticed the other answer. Copying the file is indeed a much better way here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the File.Open with a fourth parameter - fileShare.

```
FileStream stream = File.Open("myfile.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

You may need to specify write access also.

Comment: That's because you need to open it with FileShare.ReadWrite - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897796/how-do-i-open-an-already-opened-file-with-a-net-streamreader/898017#898017

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that correct opening and closing of the file please look at using the c# using statements

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open("myfile.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
{

}
```

Comment: did you understand what i am asking ? i don't want to close excel and while file is open at microsoft office excel i want to read it to my C#

Answer (score 0):

To open the same file more than once at the same time, it needs to be opened in shared mode.

Hope this may help others.