# Programmatically get user that is locking an excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, netoffice

I am using C# framework 4.5, netoffice 1.6 and sharpdevelop 4.4.1 to manipulate an excel workbook, located on a network share, from within Outlook.

At some point I need to change the file access of the workbook object (ewb) to readwrite like so:

```
ewb.ChangeFileAccess(Excel.Enums.XlFileAccess.xlReadWrite, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, true);
```

Before I change the file access, I check if the file is locked on the server. If the file is locked, I will notify the user to retry the action at a later point.

Now, I want to include the username that is locking the excel file in the notification. I have searched msdn, netoffice forum, etcetera... and have not found a solution.
I know that, if you open the excel file readwrite, it will store the user's name in the xlsx file. How can I access that particular piece of information through c#?

EDIT:
I ended up doing this:

```
public string GetExcelFileOwner(string path, NetOffice.ExcelApi.Enums.XlFileFormat ffmt) {
        string tempmark = "~$";
        if(ffmt==NetOffice.ExcelApi.Enums.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8) {
            tempmark = "";
        }
        string uspath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), tempmark + Path.GetFileName(path));
        if (!File.Exists(uspath)) return "";
        var sharing = FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete;
        using (var fs = new FileStream(uspath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, sharing))
        using (var br = new BinaryReader(fs, Encoding.Default)) {
            if(ffmt==NetOffice.ExcelApi.Enums.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8) {
                byte[] ByteBuffer = new byte[500];
                br.BaseStream.Seek(150, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                br.Read(ByteBuffer, 0, 500);
                return matchRegex(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ByteBuffer), @"(?=\w\w\w)([\w, ]+)").Trim();
            }
            else {
                return br.ReadString();
            }
        }
    }

    private static string matchRegex(string txt, string rgx) {
        Regex r;
        Match m;
        try {
            r = new Regex(rgx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            m = r.Match(txt);
            if (m.Success) {
                return m.Groups[1].Value.ToString();
            }
            else {
                return "";
            }
        }
        catch {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

We are using excel 2003 and excel 2007+ file format (.xls and .xlsx). For .xls I had to look in the .xls file itself. For .xlsx, the locking user is stored in the ~$ temp file.
I know, for the .xls file, it is dirty code, but I have no clue of how the .xls file format is structured. Therefore, i just read a bunch of bytes which includes the ascii username and do a regex to extract that username.

Comment: have you tried looking at Win32_ConnectionShare and WMIC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> it will store the user's name in the xlsx file

No, not the in .xlsx file.  Excel creates *another* file to store the user name.  It has the Hidden file attribute turned on so you cannot normally see it with Explorer.

It normally has the same name as the original file, but prefixed with `~$`.  So for a file named `test.xlsx` you'll get a file named `~$test.xlsx`.  It is a binary file and contains the user name both encoded in the default code page and in utf-16.  A hex dump to show what it looks like:

```
0000000000: 0C 48 61 6E 73 20 50 61 │ 73 73 61 6E 74 20 20 20  ♀Hans Passant
0000000010: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 │ 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
0000000020: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 │ 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
0000000030: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 0C │ 00 48 00 61 00 6E 00 73         ♀ H a n s
0000000040: 00 20 00 50 00 61 00 73 │ 00 73 00 61 00 6E 00 74     P a s s a n t
0000000050: 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 │ 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20
0000000060: 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 │ 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20
0000000070: 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 │ 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20
0000000080: 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 │ 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20
0000000090: 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 │ 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20
00000000A0: 00 20 00 20 00          │
```

The oddish 0x0C word in the file is the string length in characters (not bytes), followed by 54 characters to store the user name, padded with spaces.  Easiest way to read it is with BinaryReader.ReadString():

```
public static string GetExcelFileOwner(string path) {
    string uspath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), "~$" + Path.GetFileName(path));
    if (!File.Exists(uspath)) return "";
    var sharing = FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete;
    using (var fs = new FileStream(uspath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, sharing))
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(fs, Encoding.Default)) {
        return br.ReadString();
    }
}
```

But not necessarily the most correct way, you might want to improve the code and try to locate the utf-16 string (not with ReadString) if 8-bit encodings don't work well in your locale.  Seek() to offset 0x37 first.  Be sure to use the method correctly, it has an implicit race condition so make sure you only use it *after* the operation failed and expect an empty string return anyway.  I cannot guarantee this method will work correctly on all Excel versions, including future ones, I only tested for Office 2013 on a workstation class machine.

Comment: Hi Hans. This seems to work for local files only, not for excel files located on the network. I see the ~$ file when I open and modify an excel file on my hard drive. I don't see the file when opening from the network.

I checked the xlsx file when I opened it read/write on the network. The user's name that opened it IS stored in the xlsx.

So I still think I should read the setting from the xlsx file.

Comment: Hmm, no, pretty doubtful it is going to modify an .xlsx file just to write the user name.  The only wrinkle I can think of is that the user doesn't have write access to the shared folder.  But let's not guess at this, use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see what is happening, you'll see Excel.exe tinkering with the file(s).

Comment: Hans, you are right. Procmon is showing Excel.exe is accessing ~$......xlsx with result SUCCESS. Oh man, and now I do see the ~$....xlsx file on the server.

I also tried an xls file, for which a ~$ file is not created. The user's name is stored in the actual .xls. I will try your code and report back.

Comment: Hans, your solution works like a charm for .xlsx! Bounty coming your way soon

Answer (score 0):

Which part are you having problems with?

WIthout knowing anything about xslx, I can only guess that: you want to open file and specify FileAccess.Read & FileShare.ReadWrite as here: [How to read open excel file at C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992057/how-to-read-open-excel-file-at-c-sharp) after that, you use some kind of library to turn XSLX into DataTable, and extract the specific row which you need.

Comment: I am using the netoffice .NET Wrapper Assemblies to manipulate the office files and applications.

The problem is, I have no way of extracting the username of the user that is (b)locking the excel file.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you need to know who has opened specific file & the FLAGS it has to that file. PSFile utility can do it through command line. "psfile \\yourremoteshare C:\test.xlsx". If you are interested how to do it programmatically, you can download APIMonitor and see how psfile does it. I personally doubt that you can access the "username in the xlsx file", sounds like an internal thing to me.

Comment: Although my suggested solution requires administrator rights, which is no-no. You can use API monitor to check how does Excel receive that username from remote file. (Eg through which API calls, and is it internal)

Comment: I have no idea on how to make that happen. I downloaded API monitor from rohitab and got a trace from the excel process. How would i capture the piece of information i need?