# OleDbExecption in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, oledb, oledbexception

I have a code which can download an excel file and it will select all of its data in side. Here is my code:

```
string conn = string.Empty;
            if (Path.GetExtension(path).ToLower().Equals(".xls"))
            {
                conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
                                + path +
                                ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
            }
            else
            {
                conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
                              + path +
                              ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
            }

            string strselect = "Select * from [Sheet1$]";

            using (OleDbConnection excelCon = new OleDbConnection(conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    excelCon.Open();
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter exDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(strselect, excelCon))
                    {
                        exDA.Fill(_data);
                    }
                }
                catch (OleDbException oledb)
                {
                    throw new Exception(oledb.Message.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    excelCon.Close();
                }
            }
```

when I debugged it, in `excelCon.Open();` I get transferred in my Catch and get an OleDbException: "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data."

Can you point out what's wrong? I don't have an opened file and I checked its settings but it can be opened by anyone. Any one of you experience this kind of error?

Comment: the excel file is already opened by someone and you can;t access it

Comment: what should I do about this? and who is opening it? I don't really opened the file. :/

Comment: it is being used by some process in the system, the error says all

Comment: well yes, it is opened to get the data inside, but what should I do about it?

Comment: you open it to get and and do close after after doing whatever you want to do, otherwise you will get this exception every time

Comment: I tried debugging it again but I only see one instance well it will select or open the file. :/ Are there any other solution for this?

Comment: open it as read only, but i dont know how to

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846646/exception-in-opening-a-file-that-is-already-open

Comment: well to take note: the code I posted is for Uploading the file. So I am just trying to upload it first before I select the items.