# Opened file is not uploading

Tags: c#

I am creating a plugin for Revit in C#. This plugin will allow user to upload the working file directly to the cloud. But the problem is file is not uploading to the cloud because it is opened in application. I tried pdf files also. if file is not opened by any application it will be successfully uploaded to the cloud.

So the bug is that if file is opened by any application it cannot be uploaded to cloud.

Following code is used to read the file

```
m_FileContent = new FileStream(m_strFilePath, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: try modifying fileshare parameter - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846646/exception-in-opening-a-file-that-is-already-open

Comment: @coder_b i already tried....nut no change

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did my job by copying file to temporary folder and upload file from there.